# Self Joins and Factory Girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, factory-bot, self-join

I'm working on a website that functions like kickstarter for political candidates. Users can nominate Candidates, and they can also pledge their vote for a candidate, or contribute funds. I'm trying to define a self join where a candidate belongs to a user, but we want that user to be a nominator if they've nominated a candidate (like a creator creating a project on kickstarter). I think I've got the syntax correct, but keep getting errors when I try to seed the database.

My models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :pledges
    has_many :candidates, through: :pledges

    has_many :contributions
    has_many :candidates, through: :contributions
end

class Candidate < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :nominator, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "nominator_id"

    has_many :pledges
    has_many :users, through: :pledges

    has_many :contributions
    has_many :users, through: :contributions
end

class Pledge < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :candidate
end

class Contribution < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :candidate
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Below is my database schema file, minus devise stuff and join tables

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150714232652) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "candidates", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "affiliation"
    t.text     "platform"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
    t.integer  "nominator_id"
  end

  add_index "candidates", ["nominator_id"], name: "index_candidates_on_nominator_id", using: :btree

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at",                          null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                          null: false
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree

  add_foreign_key "contributions", "candidates"
  add_foreign_key "contributions", "users"
  add_foreign_key "pledges", "candidates"
  add_foreign_key "pledges", "users"
end
```

Here are my factories for user and candidate:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do
    name Faker::Name.name
    email Faker::Internet.safe_email
    password Faker::Internet.password
  end
end

FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :candidate do
    name Faker::Name.name
    affiliation Faker::Team.name
    platform Faker::Company.catch_phrase
    association :nominator, factory: user
  end
end
```

The error I keep getting is

> rake aborted!
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `name' for :candidate:Symbol

and it has something to do with the self join and association in the candidates factory. The error disappears when I delete that line. Any glaring errors or suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The error was a missing colon before user in my factory builder on the association line:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :candidate do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
        affiliation { Faker::Team.name }
        platform { Faker::Company.catch_phrase }
        association :nominator, factory: :user
  end
end
```